# Can we sort an IList partially?

Tags: sorting, ilist

```
IList<A_Desc,A_premium,B_Desc,B_Premium>
```

Can I sort two columns A_Desc,A_premium...based on A_Desc ?

And let B_Desc,B_Premium be remain in same order before sorting

Comment: Please rewrite your post, indenting code samples by four characters. The full declaration of IList has been swallowed because it looked like invalid HTML.

Comment: Standard `IList` is declared as `IList<T>` and doesn't have columns.

Comment: Do you mean `IDictionary` with that syntax..?

Comment: I have list...I made it type of IList becuse i can use Linq operations on that

Comment: You're not defining a sensible list here. What you need are two separate lists, and a single object that contains the values `desc` and `premium`.

Comment: I'm surrendering my answer to the community. I've written a very bad form of a custom data type to use here- I don't have time to do this right, unfortunately. If others would go ahead and refactor my answer to be a lot more helpful to you, that'd be awesome.

Comment: For two properties, it's not a good approach to use a class.

Comment: Hi Adam..Can we use two dimensional IList...I mean  "IList<IList<abcDto>>"

Comment: Why is it a poor approach to use a class for two properties? If two units of data should be represented together as one logical unit, that logical unit is a class. You should have no [fear of adding classes](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FearOfAddingClasses). You can adapt my approach to a nested IList, and make ThingieSorter sort `IList<abcDto>`, but why be vague about your data when you can make it clear and type-checked with a new class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, a list can only be of one type, and only has one "column" of data, so you actually want two lists and a data type that holds "desc" and "premium". "desc" sounds like a String to me; I don't know what Premium is, but I'll pretend it's a `double` for lack of better ideas. I don't know what this data is supposed to represent, so to me, it's just some thingie.

```
public class Thingie{
    public String desc;
    public double premium;
}
```

That is, of course, a terrible way to define the class- I should instead have desc and premium be private, and Desc and Premium as public Properties with Get and Set methods. But this is the fastest way for me to get the point across.

It's more canonical to make Thingie implement IComparable, and compare itself to other Thingie objects. But I'm editing an answer I wrote before I knew you needed to write a custom type, and had the freedom to just make it implement IComparable. So here's the IComparer approach, which lets you sort objects that don't sort themselves by telling C# how to sort them.

Implement an IComparer that operates over your custom type.

```
public class ThingieSorter: IComparer<Thingie>{
    public int Compare(Thingie t1, Thingie t2){
        int r = t1.desc.CompareTo(t2);
        if(r != 0){return r;}
        return t1.premium.CompareTo(t2);
    }
}
```

C# doesn't require IList to implement Sort- it might be inefficient if it's a LinkedList. So let's make a new list, based on arrays, which does sort efficiently, and sort it:

```
public List<Thingie> sortedOf(IList<Thingie> list){
    List<Thingie> ret = new List<Thingie>(list);
    ret.sort(new ThingieSorter());
    return ret;
}
```

`List<Thingie>` implements the interface `IList<Thingie>`, so replacing your original list with this one shouldn't break anything, as long as you have nothing holding onto the original list and magically expecting it to be sorted. If that's happening, refactor your code so it doesn't grab the reference until after your list has been sorted, since it can't be sorted in place.